# Angular + Sharepoint Rest no working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, sharepoint

First sorry my bad English.

When I try to get some items from my list doesn't work. I got the error "0x2ee7 The server name could not be resolved" in ie10 console. When I execute the all path in Dev Http in Chrome i get all right.

I think is a problem in my request because I got the "error" message with my own script.

The code are in Script Editor in my Test Page in SharePoint Online.This is my code:

```
    <div ng-app>
        <b>AngularJS + Sharepoint!</b>
        <div ng-controller="MyController" class="ng-scope">
            <div ng-repeat="p in Products">
                Product Name: {{p.ProductName}} <br />
                Rate: Rs. {{p.ProductRate}} <br />
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>    
        function MyController($scope) {
            $scope.loadREST = function () {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ProductList')/items?$select=ProductName,ProductRate",
                    type: "GET",
                    headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var newData = [];
                        jQuery.each(data.d.results, function (index, value) {
                            newData.push({ ProductName: value.ProductName, ProductRate: value.ProductRate});
                        });
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            $scope.Products = newData;
                        });
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        //alert(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
                        alert("erro de conexão");
                    }
                });
            };
            $scope.loadREST();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: test the resolution of your `url` field in your xhr call. on another note... use `$http.get` instead of `jQuery.ajax()`. it's more appropriate for the way angular works, and returns a promise object, which can be very useful

Comment: The test with the full url works fine in Chrome Dev Http but when I put the same url into my code doesn't.

Comment: What error does your console show? Sounds like an authentication problem if my experience with sp has taught me anything

Comment: I'm don't know why but works fine.

Comment: so you're saying it's working now and you don't know why and also made no changes?  If so... just delete the question. if you made changes, try to post an answer.  You *can* answer your own questions if you find a solution.

Comment: Now I uptade the code. I wonder how do I use the command $http AngularJS... some help?

Comment: a better place to learn would be here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http. Stackoverflow is intended more for solving code errors/roadblocks than it is basic tool education.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `angular.js` version 1.3.0 or above  *angular will no longer look for controllers on window*  See [3f2232b5](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3f2232b5a181512fac23775b1df4a6ebda67d018) for a more detail.

So, the controller should be initialized like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('ProductsController', [function() {
  // ...
}]);
```

instead of

```
function ProductsController() {
  // ...
}
```

Some another suggestions:

- Prefer [`$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) over `jQuery.ajax()` in Angular apps

**Modified example**

Html

```
<div ng-app="spApp">
    <b>AngularJS + Sharepoint!</b>
    <div ng-controller="ProductsController" class="ng-scope">
        <div ng-repeat="p in Products">
            Product Name: {{p.ProductName}} <br />
            Rate: Rs. {{p.ProductRate}} <br />
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('spApp',[]);

app.controller('ProductsController', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.Products = [];
    $scope.getProducts = function() {
        $http({method : 'GET',url : _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ProductList')/items?$select=ProductName,ProductRate", headers: { 'Accept':'application/json;odata=verbose' }})
           .success(function(data, status) {
               $scope.Products = data.d.results;
           })
           .error(function(data, status) {
               console.log("An error occured");
           });
      }

     $scope.getProducts();
});
```